# In ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC, how can I load *.Views.dll

Tags: asp.net-core, nopcommerce

In nopCommerce project, use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

they can load `*.views.dll`, but the same code won't work on my project. What did I miss?

Comment: Which version of Nop are you using? nopCommerce doesn't support .NET Core 3.0 yet.

Comment: Hello,Div,I use the source code,I debug their source code without errors. However, when I created a new project and copied their code, I encountered an error that failed to load *.views. DLL while debugging

Answer (score -1, accepted):

var mvcCoreBuilder = services.AddMvcCore();  //加上这行代码，就可以了.

Comment: What is this code actually doing and how is it helping butian to solve the problem? Please rewrite your comment in English so that everyone is able to understand it.

Comment: sorry！only add code var mvcCoreBuilder = services.AddMvcCore();  can solve problem；

Comment: And why? Please edit your answer and include an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In 3.1 you have to add one middle ware and from there you can get all assembly. [Follow this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.getassemblies?view=netcore-3.1#examples) hope it will solved your issue.

Comment: But can't load the mvc  razor view dll

Comment: In which nopCommerce version is  it working ? so i can get idea

Comment: clone soruce code,  in  Nop.Core.Infrastructure.AppDomainTypeFinder class  AddAssembliesInAppDomain  function

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the code  `var mvcCoreBuilder = services.AddMvcCore()` before the code you are using to load you Assemblies. That's exactly what the guys from nopcommerce did...